# why edit Button not Binding dropdown values

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here im using Mvc with Anagular i display data into table when i click on Edit button why modal popup not binding that column values.if i want to chane only name then country state values become null

**Bootstrap**

```
<div id="AssTable">
            <table class="table table-striped table-responsive ">
                <tr>
                    <th><b>Id</b></th>
                   <th> <b>CountryName</b></th>
                    <th><b>StateName</b></th>
                    <th><b>Actions</b></th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="Ass in AssData">
                    <td>{{Ass.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{Ass.CountryName}}</td>
                    <td>{{Ass.StateName}}</td>
                    <td>{{Ass.CityName}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Edit" ng-click="Edit(Ass)" />
                        </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

<div class="modal" id="modal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="f1" novalidate ng-submit="Save(emp)">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <b style="font-family:Arial;text-transform:capitalize">Enter Name</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 left-addon">
                                <input type="text" name="nam" class="form-control" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="10" ng-model="Name" ng-class="submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required autofocus />
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>


                                <span class="Error" ng-show="(f1.nam.$dirty ||submitted) && f1.nam.$error.required">Please Enter Your Name</span>
                                <span class="Error" ng-show="f1.nam.$error.minlength">Mobile number should be minimum 8 character</span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <b style="font-family: Arial; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: left">Country</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 left-addon">
                                <select name="cntr" ng-options=" I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountryList" ng-model=" CountryID" class="form-control" ng-change="GetStates()" ng-class="submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required>
                                    <option ng-repeat="d in CountryList track by $index" value="$index" ng-selected="true">{{d.CountryName}}ffff</option>
                                </select>
                                <span class="Error" ng-show="(f1.cntr.$dirty ||submitted) && f1.cntr.$error.required">Select Country</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <b style="font-family: Arial; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: left">States</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 left-addon">
                                <select name="Sts" ng-options="I.StateID as I.StateName for I in StateList" ng-model="StateID" class="form-control" ng-change="GetCities()" ng-class="submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required>

                                    <option value="">{{StateName}} </option>

                                </select>
                                <span class="Error" ng-show="(f1.Sts.$dirty ||submitted) && f1.Sts.$error.required">Select States</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" value="{{validate}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" />

                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AgularCode**

/*Country Code*/

```
 $scope.GetStates = function () {
        //  alert('ok')
        var xx = $Myservice.GetStates($scope.CountryID);
        xx.then(function (d) {
            $scope.StateList = d.data;
        })
    }
```

/*Edit AccessData*/

```
  $scope.Edit = function (Ass) {
        var editId = $Myservice.EditById(Ass.Id);
        editId.then(function () {
            $scope.Name =Ass.Name,
           $scope.CountryName = Ass.CountryName,
            $scope.CountryID=Ass.CountryID,
          $scope.StateName = Ass.StateName,
            $('#modal1').modal('show')
            $scope.validate = "UPDATE";})
    }
```

Comment: In Edit `event`?. You have setted `I.StateID as I.StateName` is this correct? On Edit you should set `$scope.StateId` to make it selectable

Comment: where ur saying

Comment: On `Edit` first you have to fill statelist from CountryId then you can set `$scope.StateId`.